# Update database when a file changed in public/ with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, guard, watch

I would like to be able to update my database when a file in public/ is modified.  The rails app use file pushed by an old system and we need to update the internal database with theses change.

Is this possible and how can i do this.  I checked for guard, but is it usable in production ?  Is there a better alternative ? Maybe i can just use dnotify, but i would like to keep everything in my project aka all in ruby and without external programs.

Thanks :P

Comment: I'm not sure why you ask if `guard` is usable in production. It absolutely is. And for "better" alternative it's important to know what you consider "better".

Comment: By usable in production I mean, will it leak memory, will it break stuff.  I don't really know guard that well. :S
And for better, I mean, what do people use in general to do that sort of thing

Comment: Why not look at the forums for `guard` and see what kind of problems people face? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guard. I personally would trust a gem that has nearly 5 million downloads. Also, this makes me think, your question isn't really a concrete programming related question, it's trust related. You should ask it on Quora ;-)

Comment: If you are unsure of using it in production, I would recommend that you stick to good old `cron` and a script written by you.

Comment: Everything I see is people want to manage their assets and test with it.  In production there's none of those.  But anyway, that's not really the point.  I juste want to know a way I could easily update my database on files changed.

Comment: Can you give any more context? Under what conditions would the file change?

Comment: https://github.com/aredridel/ruby-inotify

Comment: @RichPeck The old system push file in a certain folder from a ftp.  And it's whenever he want.  (And we don't have access to that system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guard uses a gem called [`listen`](https://github.com/guard/listen) underneath which implements the generic notifications and interfaces with the various OS modules.

Listen supports:

- Linux via [`rb-inotify`](https://github.com/nex3/rb-inotify)
- Darwin via [`rb-fsevent`](https://github.com/thibaudgg/rb-fsevent)
- Windows via [`wdm`](https://github.com/Maher4Ever/wdm) (mingw, not cygwin)
- BSD(sortof) via [`rb-kqueue`](https://github.com/mat813/rb-kqueue)
- Polling the file system every second via Ruby is the fall back option.

The modules are all basically thin veneers allowing access to the underlying OS notification system calls. You could code one of the OS specific modules directly if you want, but why would you when someone has already given you a generic interface?

Listen is fairly simple to use:

```
listener = Listen.to('dir/path/to/listen') do |modified, added, removed|
   puts "mod: #{modified}" if modified
   puts "add: #{added}"    if added
   puts "rem: #{removed}"  if removed
end
listener.start
```

You can use polling at a higher interval if you have concerns or issues with the FFI/C modules

```
options = {
  force_polling: true,
  latency:       30 
}
```

Then integrate the code to run alongside your rails app with [daemons-rails](https://github.com/mirasrael/daemons-rails)